# If $f_n(x) = \int_0^x f_{n-1}(t) dt, x \geq 0 $, then $f_n(x) = \frac {1}{(n-1)!} \int_0^x f_0(t) (x-t)^{n-1}dt$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions

If $f_0$ is continuous on $[0, \infty)$ and for all $n \in \mathbb N$, $f_n(x) = \int_0^x f_{n-1}(t) dt, x \geq 0 $, then $f_n(x) = \frac {1}{(n-1)!} \int_0^x f_0(t) (x-t)^{n-1}dt$.

It can be easily see that $f_n$ is continuous for all $n$. On Integration by parts we have $f_n(x) = \int_0^x f_{n-1}(t) dt = xf_{n-1}(x) - 0.f_{n-1}(0) - \int_0^x tf_{n-2}(t) dt  = \int_0^x (x-t)f_{n-2}(t) dt$. Again when we apply Integration by parts we have

$\int_0^x (x-t)f_{n-2}(t) dt = [f_{n-2}(t) \int (x-t)dt]_0^x + \int_0^x f_{n-3}(t) \frac{(x-t)^2}{2} dt = [f_{n-2}(t)\frac{(x-t)^2}{2}]_0^x + \int_0^x f_{n-3}(t) \frac{(x-t)^2}{2} dt = f_{n-2}(x)\frac{(x-x)^2}{2} - f_{n-2}(0)\frac{(x-0)^2}{2} + \int_0^x f_{n-3}(t) \frac{(x-t)^2}{2} dt = 0-0 + \int_0^x f_{n-3}(t) \frac{(x-t)^2}{2} dt = \int_0^x f_{n-3}(t) \frac{(x-t)^2}{2} dt$

Thus we see that $f_n(x) = \int_0^x (x-t)f_{n-2}(t) dt = \int_0^x f_{n-3}(t) \frac{(x-t)^2}{2} dt$.

Can we directly conclude from this??.. that after finite number of successive  Integration by parts we have

$f_n(x) = \frac {1}{(n-1)!} \int_0^x f_0(t) (x-t)^{n-1}dt$.

Comment: Consider induction.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $f_k(x) = \frac {1}{(k-1)!} \int_0^x f_0(t) (x-t)^{k-1}dt$ for $k=1,...,n$.

Then $f_{n+1}(x) = \int_0^x f_n(t) dt = \int_0^x \frac {1}{(n-1)!} \int_0^t f_0(s) (t-s)^{n-1}ds dt $, and using Fubini, we get
$f_{n+1}(x) = \int_0^s \int_s^x \frac {1}{(n-1)!} f_0(s) (t-s)^{n-1}dt ds  = \int_0^s \frac {1}{(n-1)!} f_0(s) \int_s^x  (t-s)^{n-1}dt ds $.

Since $\int_s^x  (t-s)^{n-1}dt = {(x-s)^n \over n}$, we have
$f_{n+1}(x) = {1 \over n!} \int_0^x f_0(t) (x-t)^n dt$.